# Getting error 1044 while making SQL table

Tags: mysql-error-1044

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv4Kq.png)

Getting error 1044 while making SQL table. I have follows all the necessary terms but still getting error.
if there is anything what you can help to solve this project please help me with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have the right permissions to create tables on that database, check this link to resolve this issue: https://serverfault.com/questions/404638/how-can-give-privilege-for-db-to-a-user-error-1044-42000-access-denied-for